# Excel - Using SUMIFS (OR) using criteria inputted in a separate cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very specific issue with the SUMIFS formula, I am positive there is a fix for this, that said I have not been able to find it.

In essence, the result of `=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A;B:B;{3;4}))` is what I am going for, however, I want the "{3;4}" to be dynamic and changeable through a cell in another worksheet (Dashboard purposes).

If I write `=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A;B:B;C1))`where `C1="{"&3;4&"}"`or `C1{=3;4}` (using ctrl+shift+enter) - I do not get the same result.

Anything I try is either treated by SUMIFS as text, or a number combination, but not as an array criteria.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Note that another option is to enter `3` in `C1` and `4` in `C2`, and then use `{=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A, B:B, C1:C2))}` (confirmed with `Ctrl` `Shift` `Enter`. But this may not suit your needs for the 'dashboard' you are trying to create.

Comment: Interesting comment Brendan, I really appreciate it, Thanks! Although, I still think there should be a particular solution, without a work-around, since the problem seems fairly fundamental.

Comment: I don't disagree, but we are dealing with Excel... `INDIRECT()` is another option you are probably aware of, but I couldn't get it to work either.

Comment: a) If you put `={3, 4}` in a cell and hit CSE you will end up with a cell that has a two dimensional array (1×2) of values. Prove by selecting C1:D1, typing `={3, 4}` and hit CSE. b) If you put =TRANSPOSE({3, 4})` in a cell and CSE it you end up with a cell containing a 2D array (2×1). Prove by selecting C1:C2, typing `=TRANSPOSE({3, 4})` and hit CSE. c) I'm unclear as to the purpose of all the cell reference acrobatics when you could just type the values into C1, C2, etc. This doesn't appear to be an intellectual exercise as a super-secret end purpose has been alluded to.

Comment: Well I just got "Jeeped"! Thanks for the input! Keep in mind that I have tried a) and b) with Sumifs ( "a" is actually in the question itself). Nothing super-secret, a matter of convenience for the way I structured my excel sheet. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a go at writing a formula that might do it:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(A:A;B:B;value(c1);B:B;value(c2)))`

writing the value function forces the cell reference into a number, I'm not clear wether you want the criteria to be an either/or (what's been written) or if you're look for an as well as (`=sum(sumifs(A:A;BB;Value(c1))+sumifs(A:A;B:B:Value(c2))`), but if you wanted an inbetween function. (`=sum(sumifs(A:A;BB;<=Value(c1))+sumifs(A:A;B:B:=>Value(c2))`)

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt add a helper column! ( Personal preference but I try to stay away from array calc's unless absolutely necessary ). Maybe try the following?

#### table1

```
+---+------+--------+
| A |  B   | helper |
+---+------+--------+
| 1 | 1    | TRUE   |
| 4 | blah | TRUE   |
| 3 | 3    | FALSE  |
| 6 | 1    | TRUE   |
| 7 | 1    | TRUE   |
| 3 | blah | TRUE   |
+---+------+--------+
```

...having a helper array named `helper` containing your acceptable inputs and looks like this:

```
+------+
|  ok  |
+------+
| 1    |
| blah |
+------+
```

..and where the "helper" column from table1 has a formula of `=COUNTIFS(helper[ok],[@B])>0`. your target `sumifs()` formula would then look something like this: `=SUMIFS(Table1[A],Table1[helper],TRUE)`. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the effort Peter! The solution is a work-around and is very similar to what Brendan said. The inputs for the helper array would be filled through separate cells. Also, with the amount of data, an additional formula next to each data value is not a great idea (especially since I am already using similar techniques for other complications..). Thanks for the time anyway :)!

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood the question. OP states "_I want the "{3;4}" to be dynamic and changeable through a cell in another worksheet_". The helper array is that dynamic input. As well, additional formula dependencies to the right of the data table shouldn't slow down the workbook too much [msdn ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). And you can always set your workbook to manual calculation for development and set back to auto for deployment. I encourage you to demo either my or Brendan's solution and report back.

Comment: Peter you understood the question correctly, I think. :) I understand your solution, however, this input, as I said in my previous comment, involves more than one cell for input. In deployment this method would be too slow, I have tested it. Thanks anyway!